# Isaiah 27:1 Why does the Leviathan need to be punished?

Tags: isaiah, creation, leviathan

**Relevant verse**:

> **Isaiah 27:1**
> ​1 In that day the Lord with his hard and great and strong sword will punish Leviathan the fleeing serpent, Leviathan the twisting serpent, and he will slay the dragon that is in the sea.

**Question:**
In Job the leviathan is presented as one of the pinnacles of God's creation. Why here does the leviathan need to be punished?

Comment: [JewishEncyclopedia.com](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13363-sea-monster) has a long article about Leviathan.  But don't bother reading it if you expect it to provide an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

When the Bible just mentions "Leviathan" without any definition -- like the mention of "stork", etc -- then it assumes the reader knows what is being referred to. So we should look around to see this word used elsewhere in the region in order to determine its meaning, and when we do, we see evidence that Leviathan is one of the [sea monsters](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Leviathan-Middle-Eastern-mythology) that so frequently appear in the Bible.

We can see, for example, in the Ugaritic Baal cycle<sup>1</sup>, the following:

```
  1–4      “When you killed Litan, the Fleeing Serpent, 156
        Annihilated the Twisty Serpent,
        The Potentate with Seven Heads,
        The heavens grew hot, they withered.

  4–6      But let me tear you to pieces,
        Let me eat flanks, innards, forearms.

  6–8      Surely you will descend into Divine Mot’s throat,
        Into the gullet of El’s Beloved, the Hero.” 157
```

Leviathan is believed to be the Hebrew version of Litan, the serpent, that was killed by Baal in the Baal Cycle. Litan was an ally of Tiamat, the primordial chaos monster killed by Baal (and before that, he was killed by Enlil, and before that, by Anu) in the Mesopotamian creation accounts, with *tiamat* the same as the hebrew תַּנִּין *tannim* - sea monster, serpent, created on day 5 in Genesis 1:21, and the only creature that is not called "good" by God (at least according to the masora). Tannim is also the word used for the serpents created by Pharaoh's magicians in Exodus 7.9 and appears in several places:

Psalm 91:13 (KJV 1900)

> Thou shalt tread upon the lion and adder:
>
> The young lion and the **dragon**[tannim] shalt thou trample under feet.

Psalm 74:13 (KJV 1900)

> Thou didst divide the sea by thy strength:
>
> Thou brakest the heads of the **dragons**[tannim] in the waters.

But how do we know that Leviathan is one of the *tannim*? In Isaiah 27.1, Leviathan is explicitly identified with the *tannim*

Isaiah 27:1 (KJV 1900)

> In that day the LORD with his sore and great and strong sword
>
> Shall punish **leviathan** the piercing serpent,
>
> **Even leviathan that crooked serpent**;
>
> And he shall slay the **dragon** [tannim] that is in the sea.

Thus Leviathan is called "the crooked serpent" and associated to the "the dragon".

So what is the dragon a symbol of? Well, we can look to the previous verse to get the context:

> For, behold, the LORD cometh out of his place **To punish the
> inhabitants of the earth** for their iniquity: The earth also shall
> disclose her blood, And shall no more cover her slain.

Thus the dragon is referencing *the inhabitants of the earth* that are being punished for their iniquity, and so *Leviathan is the inhabitants of the earth*.

We can confirm this with another line of reasoning. The inhabitants of the earth are symbolically referred to as *Egypt*. Can we therefore find an association of *tannim* with Egypt?

Ezekiel 29:3 (KJV 1900)

> 3 Speak, and say, Thus saith the Lord GOD; Behold, **I am against thee,
> Pharaoh king of Egypt, the great dragon [tannim] that lieth in the midst of his
> rivers, which hath said, My river is mine own, and I have made it for
> myself.**

And again in Ezekiel 32:2 (KJV 1900)

> 2 Son of man, take up a lamentation for Pharaoh king of Egypt, and say
> unto him, Thou art like a young lion of the nations, **and thou art as a
> whale[tannim] in the seas**: and thou camest forth with thy rivers, and
> troubledst the waters with thy feet, and fouledst their rivers.

Thus we have an association between Pharaoh, the ruler of Egypt, and *tannim*, clarifying the relationship. The *tannim* rule the inhabitants of the earth. Therefore what is being punished here is the ruler of "the inhabitants of the earth" for their iniquity, via the symbolic associations

(ruler of) inhabitants of the earth -> *tannim* -> *leviathan*.

So Leviathan is a symbol of *the world*, but not necessarily of the material world, but the spirit that controls the world - the serpent that rules the world. Spiritually, *this serpent is being punished when the inhabitants of the world are punished* and now we have an interpretation of the two verses in Isaiah 27:

Isaiah 26:21–27:1 (KJV 1900)

> ```
>   21       For, behold, the LORD cometh out of his place
>   To punish the inhabitants of the earth for their iniquity:
>   The earth also shall disclose her blood,
>   And shall no more cover her slain.
>
>   27      In that day the LORD with his sore and great and strong sword
>   Shall punish leviathan the piercing serpent,
>   Even leviathan that crooked serpent;
>   And he shall slay the dragon that is in the sea.
> ```

Some will object that God created the serpent, and it is his plaything (Ps 104.6), but God created everything and everything serves his will. Those verses are meant to describe God's *authority over the serpent*, but they do not make the serpent *undeserving of punishment*, just as God has authority over the inhabitants of the earth, and yet they are deserving of punishment "for their iniquity" - specifically all the "bloodshed that the earth will disclose".

As an addendum, we can see how this relates to Job. In Job 40-41, God asks Job to consider two supernatural creatures, *Behemot* -- the majestic plural of cattle or beast, and *Leviathan* - what we have shown is the serpent in the sea. Prior to the discovery of the Ugaritic poetry, commentators assumed Leviathan was an alligator via a folk etymology, and Behemoth was a hippopotamus via some creative interpretations of the text. But that would be silly, as man has dominion over both of these - they were even hunted for food in the ancient world - and while dangerous, they are not more dangerous than a wild bull or many other animals. Such animals would not cause Job to recognize his limitations. These creatures do, they are too much for Job (or man, in general) to contend with, as is made clear in the text.

So what is too much for man to contend with? Certainly none of the animals that God put under man's authority. No, these are *spiritual foes* that Job cannot defeat, with *Behemot* representing the flesh - the sin nature -- and *Leviathan* the dragon that rules the inhabitants of the earth.

These are forces that Job *cannot defeat*, and must rely on God to deal with.

In other words, God is telling Job "You a mortal man, a sinner, who is subject to the vagaries of the sin nature and is living in a world that is under the dominion of the dragon. You are in no place to contend with God." This finally causes Job to repent.

---

1. Mark S. Smith and Simon B. Parker, Ugaritic Narrative Poetry, vol. 9, Writings from the Ancient World (Atlanta, GA: Scholars Press, 1997), 141.

Comment: The Sea is both a monster and the abode of monsters.

Answer (score -1):

Isaiah has a different viewpoint from Job. Also from Genesis 1.21, where the sea monsters are described as a "good" creation of God. Similarly, Ps. 104 presents Leviathan as God's creation: "There [in the sea] go the ships, and Leviathan which thou didst form to sport in it." But Ps. 74 makes Leviathan God's enemy:  "Thou brakest the heads of leviathan in pieces, and gavest him to be meat to the people inhabiting the wilderness."

One explanation for these differences is that the verses which describe Leviathan as God's enemy are more "primitive," harkening back the story of the Lord Ba'al's victory over the sea deity Yam. The verses that describe Leviathan as part of God's good creation represent a more "advanced" theology in which God is sovereign over all things, including the monstrous beings that live in the sea.

In terms of why Leviathan needed punishment, in the Ba'al story Yam had been favored over Ba'al by El. But "Fearsome Yam came to rule the Gods with an iron fist. He caused them to labor and toil under His reign." Yam also caused Asherah to offer herself to him. So Ba'al conquered Yam. The biblical authors, of course, did not share this polytheistic view but the archetype of the true deity conquering the sea monster survived. An article on Yam and his relationship the biblical tradition can be found here. https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Yam_(god)